# How to create this append record?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table full with employees structured as:

```
tblEmployees
+--------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| EmployeeID   |  FirstName |  LastName |  Wage |
+--------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

I then have a table which the user can paste data into from an external software which looks like so:

```
tblImport
+------------+-----------+--------------+
| EmployeeID |  WorkDate |  HoursWorked |
+------------+-----------+--------------+
```

This will then go into another table (`HoursWorkedRecords`) which is structured the same way.

When I append from the import table to the main table what I would like is firstly:

- The append to check if the `EmployeeID` pasted into the `tblImport` table exists in `tblEmployees`, if so then it append to `HoursWorkedRecords`.
- Before importing check there are no duplicate records by the `EmployeeID` on that given `WorkDate`.

My question is how can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you using to paste/manage the data - VBA/Access queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query to do this. If you use a `LEFT JOIN` between `HoursWorkedRecords` and `tblEmployees` on `EmployeeID` then any null entries in your employees table will signify hours worked records where the employee could not be found. You can either use this query directly or through a VBA module.

The (untested) SQL for the query is

```
SELECT
    HWR.EmployeeID
FROM HoursWorkedRecords AS HWR
    JOIN tblEmployees AS TE
    ON HWR.EmployeeID  = TE.EmployeeID 
WHERE
    TE.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on how you wish to proceed should either of your requirements fail to be met:

- What should happen if the `EmployeeID` is **not** found in the `tblEmployees` table?
- What should happen if there **are** duplicates found in the `HoursWorkedRecords` table?

If the answer to these questions is to simply ignore the records which do not meet the criteria, then this can be achieved with a relatively simply `INSERT` query:

```sql
insert into hoursworkedrecords
select 
    i.employeeid, i.workdate, i.hoursworked
from 
    (tblimport i inner join tblemployees e on i.employeeid = e.employeeid) 
    left join hoursworkedrecords h on i.employeeid = h.employeeid and i.workdate = h.workdate
where 
    h.employeeid is null
```

Here, the `inner join` on the `tblEmployees` table ensures that the `EmployeeID` is valid, and the `left join` on the `hoursworkedrecords` table in conjunction with the `is null` criteria ensures that a record for that employee on that date does not exist.

If however, the user should be alerted to these issues, you should use the reverse of the above query to select the invalid records for the user to review before proceeding.